# How to disable autodesk-forge mouseHover on panel

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to add some CSS on a forge panel.
Whenever I put my mouse hover a forge panel the colour of the background become darker.

Is it possible to disable this behaviour? 
Edited:

[Here picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4yEb.png)

My mouse was hover the panel titled 2.

I want the background to stay like the panel 1.

Comment: Could you consider providing a reproducible case demonstrating how you create these two panels? I tried to reproduce the situation you mentioned, but unfortunately I couldn't. All panels I created are all transparent like your panel 2.

Comment: I might have found the problem. We're using the third version of the forge viewer on the 6th version the problem doesn't appear. We are going to upgrade the viewer thx for your help

Comment: Sure thing, thank you for confirming. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem doesn't appear in the last version of the forge viewer. I'm gooing to upgrade my viewer

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that you want to change the background color of the tree nodes of the model structure panel or property panel while mouse hovering. Please place this CSS snippet after viewer's stylesheet:

```
// Change background color to red color in dark-theme
.adsk-viewing-viewer.dark-theme .treeview .group>lmvheader:hover,
.adsk-viewing-viewer.dark-theme .treeview .leaf>lmvheader:hover,
.adsk-viewing-viewer.dark-theme .treeview group>lmvheader:hover,
.adsk-viewing-viewer.dark-theme .treeview leaf>lmvheader:hover {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,.4)!important;
}

// Change background color to red color in light-theme
.adsk-viewing-viewer.light-theme .treeview .group>lmvheader:hover,
.adsk-viewing-viewer.light-theme .treeview .leaf>lmvheader:hover,
.adsk-viewing-viewer.light-theme .treeview group>lmvheader:hover,
.adsk-viewing-viewer.light-theme .treeview leaf>lmvheader:hover {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,.4)!important;
}
```

And here you go!

[image]

Comment: sorry I have poorly explained my problem. I edited my question and an image. To show my problem